# Possible to re-use a Fragment instance across multiple Activities?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-support-library

If I add a `Fragment` instance to `Activity` `A` as follows...

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
  .beginTransaction()
  .add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment, "MY_FRAGMENT_TAG")
  .commit();
```

... And then I start `Activity` `B` on top of `Activity` `A`. Is it possible (?) to get a handle on the previously committed `Fragment` instance in `Activity` `B` something as follows...

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
  .findFragmentByTag("MY_FRAGMENT_TAG");
```

... This returns `null` so I wonder if this is possible using the approach above or otherwise??

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the FragmentManager handles things on an Activity level, ie what you see in Activity A does not exist in Activity B until you actually reproduce it there. Don't quote me on that though. :)

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034186/retain-fragment-state-between-activities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible, you can use Fragments only in its FragmentActivity.

In SDK doc, it says A Fragment is a piece of an application's user interface or behavior that can be placed in an Activity. **A Fragment is closely tied to the Activity it is in, and can not be used apart from one.**
So, you can't.

Please read the reference document: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html